# How to cleanup a failed ApiPromise after initialising

Tags: polkadot-js

Currently trying to create a way to attempt a new `ApiPromise` .If a specific RPC is deemed to be down / unavailable

Code basically looks like this

```typescript
const api = await ApiPromise.create({
                    provider: new WsProvider(endpoint),
                    rpc: polkadotApiRpc,
                    types: polkadotApiTypes,
                    noInitWarn: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                    throwOnConnect: true,
                });
```

When the endpoint is unavailable it successfully throws,
however the attempts to continue to connect to the websocket endpoint continues.

Is there anyway to properly **cleanup** the ApiPromise so that it doesn't spam the console, as in if it throws, nothing is leftover.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `on` handler:

```js
const provider = new WsProvider(endpoint);
provider.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("There was an error with the websocket connection")
    // console.error("Connection error:", error);
    process.exit(1);
});

const api = new ApiPromise({ provider });
await api.isReadyOrError;

const chain = await api.rpc.system.chain();
const nodeName = await api.rpc.system.name();
const nodeVersion = await api.rpc.system.version();

console.log(`You are connected to chain ${chain} using ${nodeName} v${nodeVersion}`);
process.exit()
```

Resources

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/create/#advanced-creation
- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/create/#failures

Comment: Thank you so much, this was in the context of FE code, so no Node methods,
but it was the right direction.
Solved it using this. Will post as separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix based on Bruno's answer above

```typescript
const wsProvider = new WsProvider(endpoint);
                try {
                    const api = await ApiPromise.create({
                        provider: wsProvider,
                        rpc: polkadotApiRpc,
                        types: polkadotApiTypes,
                        noInitWarn: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                        throwOnConnect: true,
                    });

                    console.log(networkType, 'api');
                    await api.isReadyOrError;
                    console.log(networkType, 'api, is ready or error');
                    return api;
                } catch (ex) {
                    //  cleanup sockets on error
                    wsProvider.disconnect();
                    throw ex;
                }
```